# Rebar control, what causes a RBN_AUTOBREAK notification to be sent

Tags: windows, user-interface

One of the notifications sent by a rebar control is RBN_AUTOBREAK.

I have a generic event handler for a rebar control and I want to test for RBN_AUTOBREAK.  But, I can't figure out how to get the control to send that notification.  Does anyone know what combination of things would cause the notification to be sent?

Comment: Keep in mind that it is sent to the parent window as a WM_NOTIFY message.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Hans.  I do look for a WM_NOTIFY message with the RBN_AUTOBREAK code.